# RESTful design for multiple responses with single endpoint

Tags: rest, swagger, design-principles

I'm working on the project which provides REST API.
Recently we decided to integrate it with Swagger to create detailed documentation for each endpoint.
Almost all RESTs were successfully integrated but for some of them we encountered few difficulties.

So, we have a REST with "/users" resource which by default returns list of  users by given criterias in JSON format, e.g. :

```
[
{
    name: "user1",
    age: 50,
    group: "group1"
},
{
    name: "user2",
    age: 30,
    group: "group2"
},
{
    name: "user3",
    age: 20,
    group: "group1"
}
]
```

One of the requirements to this REST was to group users by "**group**" field and provide response with following format:

```
[
    group1: [ 
        {
            name: "user1",
            age: 50,
            group: "group1"
        },
        {
            name: "user3",
            age: 20,
            group: "group1"
        }]
    group2: [
        {
            name: "user2",
            age: 30,
            group: "group2"
         }
    ]
]
```

We provide such response when query param **groupby** equals to "group".
So, the problem is that Swagger allows to provide only single response format by single endpoint(method and response code). E.g. we can't provide 2 response formats for **/users** endpoint "**200**" response code and **GET** HTTP method.

And now I'm absolutely confused about the way how to change our REST design in order to make it Swagger compatible.

**Notes:**
It seems to incorrect to add new endpoint for groupped users  as far as according to the REST design principles **grouped users** are not a separate resource but just additional representation of  existing resource.

Swagger is not a strict requirement so any ideas regarding other REST documentation tools would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out, you return two different formats (representations) in your two use cases. Ungrouped users are returned as an array (collection) of users. When you append a `groupBy` query parameter you return something completely different - a set of **search results**.

If you want to do a RESTful search, treat a search as a resource of its own. The downside is that it will require two requests to the server to get a response: one to create a `search` object and return a 201 with an appropriate `Location` header and a link to search results, and one another request to retrieve results for this search. The upside is that is will work with Swagger and you an reuse the pattern for other resources.

Alternatively, if you only need to group users by *one* parameter - group, you can indeed add an extra resource: `/user-groups` as you are effectively retrieving **all** groups of users with user collections embedded.

Comment: Could you please provide some details about part with 201 response code, or give some example

Comment: When you create a new search resource by `POST`ing to `/searches` you should return a status code of `201 CREATED` and a `Location` header with the URI of the search (not its results!) as the value. You should also return a _link_ to the result of this search. Calling the URI on that link would return a search result representation which you can craft for grouping. For example: `totalCount: 10, groups: [ {name: "group1", results: [{name: "user2", group: "group1"...}, {...}...]} ]` . This would be restful but quite high maintenance so do consider the simpler `user-groups` option.